# How to make apt to ignore the dependencies?

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I was trying to remove Clementine but the problem is that the apt thinks sees that some packages require packages that the dpkg won't execute because of a conflict. I tried with apt --fix-broken install but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

This is what I got:

> apt --fix-broken install Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Correcting
>   dependencies... Done The following packages were automatically
>   installed and are no longer required:   casefile clamz fonts-roboto
>   fonts-roboto-hinted jsql kio-audiocd libass5   libavformat56
>   libblas-common libbluray1 libcamel-1.2-59 libcoin80v5
>   libcrossguid0v4 libdap23 libebook-1.2-16 libebur128-1 libemu2
>   libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-openssl-2.0-5 libevent-pthreads-2.0-5
>   libgfortran3 libgif4 libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-autoar-common
>   libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgtop-2.0-10 libhunspell-1.4-0 libjasper1
>   libjim0.76 libjs-iscroll libjs-mochikit libkcddb4 libkcompactdisc4
>   libloudmouth1-0 liblouis12 liblua5.1-0 libluajit-5.1-2
>   libluajit-5.1-common   libmicrohttpd10 libmysqlclient18
>   libnepomukcore4 libntfs-3g871 libobs0   libopenscenegraph100v5
>   libopenthreads20 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0   libpcre16-3
>   libpcrecpp0 libperl5.24 libpoppler64 libqgis-core2.14.11
>   libqgis-gui2.14.11 libqgis-networkanalysis2.14.11 libqgispython2.14.11
>   libqgsttools-p1 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediawidgets5
>   libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network
>   libqtscript4-sql   libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml
>   libradare2-1.1 libtag-extras1   libtinyxml2.6.2
>   libtracker-control-1.0-0 libtracker-miner-1.0-0
>   libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 liburcu4 libwebpmux2 libwireshark8 libwiretap6
>   libwsutil7 libx265-95 libxine2 libxine2-bin libxine2-doc
>   libxine2-ffmpeg   libxine2-misc-plugins libxine2-plugins maltegoce
>   nepomuk-core-data   obs-plugins python-advancedhttpserver
>   python-alembic python-boltons   python-cheetah python-dap
>   python-editor python-formencode python-geoip2   python-geojson
>   python-icalendar python-maxminddb python-mpltoolkits.basemap
>   python-openid python-pampy python-paste python-pastedeploy
>   python-pastedeploy-tpl python-pastescript python-pluginbase
>   python-pylibemu   python-pyotp python-scgi python-smoke-zephyr
>   python-tempita python-tzlocal   python-unicorn rename Use 'apt
>   autoremove' to remove them. The following additional packages will be
>   installed:   libsidplay1 libtag1c2a Suggested packages:   sidplay-base
>   xsidplay The following NEW packages will be installed:   libsidplay1
>   libtag1c2a 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not
>   upgraded. 23 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/84.7 kB
>   of archives. After this operation, 304 kB of additional disk space
>   will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y dpkg: regarding
>   .../libtag1c2a_1.9.1-2.1_amd64.deb containing libtag1c2a:amd64: 
>   libtag1v5:amd64 conflicts with libtag1c2a   libtag1c2a:amd64 (version
>   1.9.1-2.1) is to be installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing archive
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libtag1c2a_1.9.1-2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
>   conflicting packages - not installing libtag1c2a:amd64 dpkg: regarding
>   .../libsidplay1_1.36.59-6_amd64.deb containing libsidplay1: 
>   libsidplay1v5 conflicts with libsidplay1   libsidplay1 (version
>   1.36.59-6) is to be installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing archive
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libsidplay1_1.36.59-6_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
>   conflicting packages - not installing libsidplay1 Errors were
>   encountered while processing: 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libtag1c2a_1.9.1-2.1_amd64.deb 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libsidplay1_1.36.59-6_amd64.deb E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you ever mix other repositories than official Debian? That's the usual cause for this when newer packages than available conflict and won't be replaced. You can try to force Debian stable to install over other (newer) versions by temporarily pinning stable preferences to >= 1001 (instead of default 500) in apt pinning (`man apt_preferences` or see https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences). Check also the output of `apt-cache policy` or `apt-cache policy packagegivingtrouble`. Also having 23 packets half installed isn't helping (and requires this --fix-broken for apt to even want to work)

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`